# Importing Modules in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

Consider I have following files

```
 -- index.js  [app dir]
 -- node_modules/requestHandler.js
 -- node_modules/log4js
```

I include log4js and requestHandler modules in my index.js and configure logger with my log4js.json

Now if I include log4js again in my requestHandler.js module, would the configurations set by index.js persist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

`require` caches node modules. But you are configuring log4js in index.js. If log4js were to configure itself when you first require it, then yes the configuration would persist.

Comment: Thank you.. But How can i access the logger instance created in index.js from requestHandler.js rather passing it as an argument in node? Is there a concept of inheritance that can be achieved via modules?

Comment: You could pass the instance as an argument when requiring other files `require('file.js')(logger);`. You could also make a file that instanstiates the logger, then exports it, and require that file whereever you need the logger.